# Laravel: How can I fopen() a file in a local directory?

Tags: php, laravel, csv, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8.

I have a `.csv` file stored in `/public/data/object.csv`. I want to seed a table by parsing this file. This `.csv` file has `\n` in the strings enclosed by `"`

I tried to import the `.csv` directly into mySQL, but I'm receiving an error that I have less fields that needed on a given line. I checked with Python and my file is okay (all records have four fields), so I think this must be a problem with the mySQL's .csv parser... So I want to create a seeder that reads the file line by line, prints in the console how many fields I have for a given record, do the parsing and create the models using the ORM.

I know this is not effective or optimal, but this would be a one-time operation.

Now the thing is... how do I access the `.csv` file?

I have stored it in the Seeders directory, so foolishly I thought this would've work:

```
//...
class ObjectSeeder extends Seeder
{
  public function run()
  {
    $file = fopen('objetos.csv', 'r');
    // ...
    fclose($file);
  }
}
//...
```

This throws an exception: `fopen(objetos.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. So I have changed the file to be in `/public/data`, `/storage/app/data` and can't access them with routes such as `../public/data/objects.csv`

When the file is in the storage, I can access it via `$content = Storage::disk('local')->get('data/schedule.dat');`. Problem is I can't parse the string using `fgetcsv()` because it's not a file handler. I can't break the file by `\n` to use `str_getcsv()` because as I said, the file contains strings with `\n`

I know this must be super basic and its only an issue on **WHERE** to put the file so I can have a **real** file handler.

Comment: Any file starting with `/` will look for it starting in the **system** root, not the project root. `/public/data` will not be correct

Comment: I tried to open them as `../public/data` also as `./objetos.csv` when stored in the Seeder directory, also as `public_path('/public/data')` and such... I already know what you say, thanks

Comment: try `fopen(public_path('data/objetos.csv', 'r'));`

Comment: That's the correct answer... I made it work finally, thanks a lot!